# Memory leak without the use of new operator in C++

Tags: c++, memory-leaks

I am currently in the process of recreating a basic linux shell for my class and I'm having problems with valgrind detecting a memory leak even without the use of the new operator. I'm not sure where to look at and I can't make anything out of the valgrind error message. If anyone has any idea where the memory leak is coming from, that would be very appreciated. Thank you!

```
==26432== 
==26432== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26432==     in use at exit: 61 bytes in 2 blocks
==26432==   total heap usage: 268 allocs, 266 frees, 28,546 bytes allocated
==26432== 
==26432== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==26432==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1DCA: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1E63: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EACF5E: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x401895: main (in /home/randyhe/Documents/FALL2015/CS100/rshell/bin/rshell)
==26432== 
==26432== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==26432==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF2930: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF2D47: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x401826: main (in /home/randyhe/Documents/FALL2015/CS100/rshell/bin/rshell)
==26432== 
==26432== LEAK SUMMARY:
==26432==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26432==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26432==      possibly lost: 61 bytes in 2 blocks
==26432==    still reachable: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26432==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==26432== 
==26432== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
```

A portion of my code is below.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <utility>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <pwd.h>

std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >, std::queue<std::string> >
    parseInput(std::string s, bool& b);
void check(std::string singleWord, std::string keyword, bool& b, int& index,
        std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v, std::queue<std::string>& q);
void executeAll(std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >,
    std::queue<std::string> > p);
void printCommands(const std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >& v);
void printConnectors(std::queue<std::string> q);
bool executeSingle(std::vector<std::string>& v);
std::vector<char*> toCharPointers(std::vector<std::string>& v);
char* getHost();

int main()
{
    // Store hostname into character array object hostname
    char hostname[HOST_NAME_MAX];
    int status = gethostname(hostname, HOST_NAME_MAX);
    if(status != 0)
    {
        perror("gethostname failed");
        exit(errno);
    }

    // Store username to login object
    struct passwd *pws;
    pws = getpwuid(geteuid());
    if(pws == NULL)
    {
        perror("getid failed");
        exit(errno);
    }
    std::string login = pws->pw_name;

    for(;;)
    {
        // Output login and hostname
        std::cout << login << "@" << hostname << "$ ";

        // Get user input
        std::string userInput;
        std::getline(std::cin, userInput);

        // If user inputs exit, end program
        if(userInput == "exit")
            exit(0);

        // parsedPair holds the list of commands on its .first, and holds
        // the list of connectors on its .second
        bool correctSyntax = true;
        std::pair<std::vector<std::vector<std::string> >, 
            std::queue<std::string> > parsedPair = 
                parseInput(userInput, correctSyntax);

        if(correctSyntax)
            executeAll(parsedPair);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: IIRC, `exit` doesn't lead to proper destruction of objects (it's not meant for "graceful" exits). Try `return 0;` instead.

Comment: Surely this could be stripped down more, I have a hard time believing that every single line of your original code is necessary to reproduce the issue.

Comment: You probably want to use `std::vector<std::string>` instead of `std::vector<char*>`

Comment: If you had compiled using `-g` flag, you would have had line numbers to help you follow Valgrind's messages.  As it is, it's still evident that you have created a `std::string` in `main()` and another by reading from a `std::istream`.  I don't have time to dig into your code fully (is that really a _minimal_ complete example?) but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: quick and simple answer @molbdnilo thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you know how to read it, you will see exactly what is going on:

```
==26432== HEAP SUMMARY:
==26432==     in use at exit: 61 bytes in 2 blocks
==26432==   total heap usage: 268 allocs, 266 frees, 28,546 bytes allocated
==26432== 
==26432== 29 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 2
==26432==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1DCA: std::string::_Rep::_M_clone(std::allocator<char> const&, unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1E63: std::string::reserve(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EACF5E: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x401895: main (in /home/randyhe/Documents/FALL2015/CS100/rshell/bin/rshell)
==26432== 
==26432== 32 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 2 of 2
==26432==    at 0x4C2B0E0: operator new(unsigned long) (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==26432==    by 0x4EF1208: std::string::_Rep::_S_create(unsigned long, unsigned long, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF2930: char* std::string::_S_construct<char const*>(char const*, char const*, std::allocator<char> const&, std::forward_iterator_tag) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x4EF2D47: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
==26432==    by 0x401826: main (in /home/randyhe/Documents/FALL2015/CS100/rshell/bin/rshell)
==26432==
```

This:

```
==26432==    by 0x4EACF5E: std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >& std::getline<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char, std::char_traits<char> >&, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >&, char) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
```

and this:

```
==26432==    by 0x4EF2D47: std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >::basic_string(char const*, std::allocator<char> const&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.19)
```

are the constructors for strings (which calls `new`).

As the comment says, don't call `exit(0);` to get out of your loop, either use `break` or `return 0` - that way the destructors for local objects at the end of `main` will be called, and the memory for your string variables released.

Bear in mind that `exit` is not something the C++ compiler recognizes with respect to what happens to objects. It's just a giant `goto` that exits your program. It does do SOME cleanup, like closing files, but does not clean up any objects. The same applies to `setjmp`/`longjmp` pairs - C++ will not clean up for those.

If you want to exit from a function that is called from `main`, one solution would be to throw an exception that is caught in `main`.

Of course, if you are exiting the program, a few memory leaks of this kind isn't terrible - it's a balance between cleaning up and making the code more complex. In this particular case, it's very easy to fix, so I would fix it. But if you have to make lots and lots of changes just to chase down a memory leak of a couple of objects that last the entire duration of the program, then it's not a huge issue (it's NICE to fix them, but not essential). The BAD memory leaks are the ones that leak something for every iteration of a loop or every call of a commonly called function - that's when your program will eventually own all the memory it can, and cause a problem.

Comment: Thank you! Replacing exit to return 0 worked flawlessly and valgrind did not detect any memory leaks! :)